# Initialize an Array inside AWK Command and use the Array to Print using AWK

Tags: bash, awk

Im trying to Do a Comparison of 2 File Data and print certain out out of it.

My objective mainly here is to initlize an araay containing some values inside the same awk statement and use it for some printing purpose.

Below is the Command i am using which i feel looking like some syntactical error.

Please Help in the AWK part how I should define the Array also How i cna use it inside it.

Command tried -

```
paste -d "|" filedata.txt tabdata.txt | awk -F '|' '{array=("RE_LOG_ID" "FILE_RUN_ID" "FH_RECORDTYPE" "FILECATEGORY")}' '{c=NF/2;for(i=1;i<=c;i++)if($i!=$(i+c))printf "%s|%s|%s|%s\n",$1,${array[i]},$i,$(i+c)}'
```

SAMPLE INPUT FILE

filedata.txt

```
A|1|2|3
B|2|3|4
```

tabdata.txt

```
A|1|4|3
B|2|3|7
```

So my Output i am wanting is . -

```
A|FH_RECORDTYPE|2|4
B|FILECATEGORY|4|7
```

The Output Comprises the Differences -

```
PRIMARYKEY|COLUMNNAME|FILE1DATA|FILE2DATA
```

I want the Array to be initialized inside the AWK as array=("RE_LOG_ID" "FILE_RUN_ID" "FH_RECORDTYPE" "FILECATEGORY") and will correspond Column Names

The fetching columnname from the array-  condition will be when ($i!=$(i+c)) whichever "i"th position mismatches i will print the "i" th Element from the Array.

Finding the Differences Section is working perfect if i remove the array part from my command, but my ask is i want to initialize an array containing the column names and print it too within the awk statement.

Just i need help how to incorporate the Array Part within AWK.

Comment: please post sample Input_file and expected sample output in your post in code tags and let us know then.

Comment: Updated with Sample Example

Comment: Samrat, please explain it more clearly like how `FH_RECORDTYPE` is coming in output? Please add more details to your question.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 -- If you see my Command tried those are the Array Elements which i want..

Comment: yes, I am getting it that you want to insert some text on specific conditions but your conditions are NOT clear. Please spend sometime to redefine your post.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 The condition of insertion will be when ($i!=$(i+c)) whichever "i"th position mismatches i will print the "i" th Element from the Array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately arrays in AWK cannot be assigned as you expect. As an alternative, you can use `split` function like:

```
split("RE_LOG_ID FILE_RUN_ID FH_RECORDTYPE FILECATEGORY", array, " ")
```

(Optional " " is needed because FS is overwritten.)
Then your command will look like:

```
paste -d "|" filedata.txt tabdata.txt | awk -F '|' '
BEGIN {split("RE_LOG_ID FILE_RUN_ID FH_RECORDTYPE FILECATEGORY", array, " ")}
{
    c= NF/2;
    for(i=1; i<=c; i++)
        if ($i != $(i+c))
            printf "%s|%s|%s|%s\n", $1, array[i], $i, $(i+c);
}'
```

Comment: The above working completely as expected but i wanted to ask one additional variance. For example  let me i have the column name "RE_LOG_ID FILE_RUN_ID FH_RECORDTYPE FILECATEGORY" in a variable like as below -    colnames="RE_LOG_ID FILE_RUN_ID FH_RECORDTYPE FILECATEGORY"  , now i m trying to replace the command with the variable it looks like not working, can u add your comment on it please -

Comment: paste -d "|" newfile1.dat newfile2.dat | awk -F '|' '
BEGIN {split("$colnames",array," ")}
{
c= NF/2;
for(i=1; i<=c; i++)
if ($i != $(i+c))
printf "%s|%s|%s|%s\n", $1, array[i], $i, $(i+c);
}'

Comment: There will be several ways to pass shell variables to AWK script.
One is "variable expansion" as you are trying. In that case we need to quote the whole script block with not single quotes, but double quotes to enable variable expansion.
Then we need to add backslashes to escape characters that otherwise have a special meaning within double quotes.

Comment: `colnames="RE_LOG_ID FILE_RUN_ID FH_RECORDTYPE FILECATEGORY"

paste -d "|" newfile1.dat newfile2.dat | awk -F '|' "
BEGIN {split(\"$colnames\",array,\" \")}
{ c= NF/2;
  for(i=1; i<=c; i++)
    if (\$i != \$(i+c)) printf \"%s|%s|%s|%s\n\", \$1, array[i], \$i, \$(i+c);
}"` In my opinion I do not recommend it due to messy escapings.

Comment: Another option is to make use of -v option of AWK:
`colnames="RE_LOG_ID FILE_RUN_ID FH_RECORDTYPE FILECATEGORY"

paste -d "|" newfile1.dat newfile2.dat | awk -F '|' -v colnames=$colnames '
BEGIN {split(colnames,array," ")}
{ c= NF/2;
  for(i=1; i<=c; i++)
    if ($i != $(i+c)) printf "%s|%s|%s|%s\n", $1, array[i], $i, $(i+c);
}'`

Comment: Note that the variable name "colnames" just happens to be same in the assignment and it may look confusing but the point is that the left-hand side is a variable name which is referred in AWK script and the right-hand side is a value which is assigned in shell.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I finally found this. Nice with a confirmative answer, though I find it very disturbing that language documentation often tries to hide the flaws of the language by not mentioning this kind of things. It would be much nice with "array literals are created by using the split() function", rather than "it is also possible to use split to create arrays". Which hides the fact that this is the only (realistic) way to create array literals. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: I do agree. It's my pleasure to know my previous post helps you. BR.